# Implement my own std::istream reading from a home made stream of byte

Tags: c++, stl, derived-class, istream

On one hand I have a nice c++ function taking an `istream&` as parameter.
On the other hand I have a old school home made stream of bytes (kind of open/read/close stuff).

And, of course, I want to plug the second into the first.

I tried to create a derived class from `streambuf` and pass it to the `istream`'s constructor. But it seems that `streambuf`'s methods are not virtual...

What is the right way to do it ?
Thanks !

Comment: Look again, `std::streambuf` has several virtual methods for you to override so you can read and write your byte data

Comment: [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), there are a lot of virtual methods in there, especially `underflow`, and `overflow`. Which non-virtual method would you like to override ? (btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086417/how-to-write-custom-input-stream-in-c )

Comment: I thought that the most significant methods for me were `sbumpc`, `sgetn` and `snextc`. But those are not virtual (at least in my Visual Studio 2010 stl).

Comment: My mistake! I didn't see the protected methods which are those I need.