# how to convert Concurrency::streams::istream to std::istream in c++

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I was coding with [CppRESTsdk](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespace_concurrency_1_1streams.html) and got `Concurrency::streams::istream` from the response body like the following code:

```
web::http::http_response localVarResponse;
auto concurrencyStream = localVarResponse.body();
```

I want to convert the stream to `std::istream` and use it inside `std::shared_ptr` so that I can pass it to other classes like this:

```
std::istream stdStream = concurrencyStream;
auto istream_ptr = std::make_shared<std::istream>(stdStream);
```

But I got errors:

```
 E0312  no suitable user-defined conversion from 
    "Concurrency::streams::istream" to "std::istream" exists
```

How can I convert to `std::istream`?

**EDIT**: indirectly via [std::streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/) it works.

```
std::string str = localVarResponse.content_ready().get().extract_utf8string(true).get();
std::istringstream SStream(str);
std::istream inputStream(SStream.rdbuf());
```

Comment: It might help if you share the errors that you get. `I get errors` is not very informative.

Comment: Looking at the documentation the types are unrelated. Therefore the only possible technique would be to write a `std::streambuf` derived class to forward requests to a contained concurrency::stream stream buffer. For example see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086417/how-to-write-custom-input-stream-in-c, although google will show many more tutorials, this is a common topic.