# How to use regular std::basic_istream::read, std::basic_ostream::write on a buffer of data in memory?

Tags: c++, qt, file, buffer

I have a `QByteArray` and want to use it like a regular text file. How can I use functions like `std::basic_istream::read` on it ?

Comment: This thread may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086417/how-to-write-custom-input-stream-in-c

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work. Is there a particular reason why you don't `std::copy()` or `std::copy_n` from it using its `begin()` (and possibly `end()`) iterator(s)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, You mean i copy it into another container ? as what  John Park said ?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Since Qt's iterators are STL compatible you can use them as you would use any STL iterator. You can also do `std::string from_byte_array(qt_byte_array.begin(), qt_byte_array.end());` to copy out the data or if you don't want to copy: `std::string_view view_over_byte_array(qt_byte_array.begin(), qt_byte_array.size());` should be fine too. I didn't make an answer out of it since you specifically said that you wanted to use it as a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QByteArray data type is close to a container, not a stream. You can't handle it like a text file unless you inherit std::streambuf class that handles QByteArray internally.

You can also consider converting std::stringstream to QByteArray if you don't care of performance,

```
std::stringstream ss;
// write to ss ...
.
.
QByteArray qdata = QByteArray::fromStdString(ss.str());
```

for read operation,

```
QByteArray qdata; // consider qdata is already filled with data.
std::stringstream ss(qdata.toStdString());
```