# How to extend ifstream?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ifstream

I would like to extend `ifstream` by defining a new class `ifstreamExt` where :

1. there is a class variable called 'directory' that is a string and that holds the location where the file will be opened.
2. the open method is redefined so to use the `directory` variable.
3. and finally, `>>` is supposed to work with string at least.

I managed to do 1 & 2 - but I am failing with 3. I do not know how to write it, I made multiple trials. The first one was using `getline`, it worked fine, but not as `>>` works ; this operator skips blanks and retrieve consecutive non-blanks character, whereas getline gets the full line and does not pick each of sub-string.

```
class ifstreamExt : ifstream {
  public:

    void open(string f) {
      string s = h + "/" + f;
      name = s;
      if (!is_open()) {
        cerr << "cannot open " << s << endl;
        exit(1);
      } else {
        cerr << "open file " << s << endl;
      }
    }
    friend ifstreamExt & operator >> (ifstreamExt & is, string &str) {
    }

    static void set_directory(string d) {
      cerr << "set home directory : " << d << endl;
      h = d;
      DIR* dir = opendir(h.c_str());
      if (dir) {
        cerr << "directory " << h << " exists " << endl;
      } else {
        cerr << "directory " << h << " does not exist " << endl;
        exit(1);
      }
    }
  private :
    static string h;
};
```

Comment: I would not inherit `std::ifstream`, but instead create my own totally independent class that uses *composition* to have a private `std::ifstream` member to be used. Create a templated extraction operator that forwards to the streams own operator.

Comment: Since your class inherits from `ifstream` then `std::getline` and `operator>>` will work with your class already. There's no need to add more code.

Comment: On a different note, please read [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std) Doing it in a header file is considered by many to be just plain wrong.

Comment: Unrelated: fear the 1-letter variable name. They lead to so many bugs it's not funny. I mean really not funny. People mix them up all the time and the human brain sucks at noticing they were swapped. People reading your code, including you a few weeks down the line, draw the wrong inferences by misinterpreting the purpose of the variable and insert new bugs based on the bad interpretation. Instead chose variable names that describe the variable. Pick good names and the code will be almost self-documenting.

Comment: Note that most of the standard library classes are not intended to be inherited from. Streams are a bit of an exception, but still you should not derive from std::ifstream directly. More info here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086417/how-to-write-custom-input-stream-in-c

Comment: @john: That would be true with public inheritance, but in this case they used private inheritance.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Good point, maybe public inheritance was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Following the recommendations posted in the comments, here is ifstreamExt which is a new class with composition. Any feedback welcome !

```
class ifstreamExt {
  public :
    ifstreamExt() : file_() { }
    void open(const std::string &filename) {
      string f_name = _dir_ + "/" + filename;
      file_.open(f_name);
      if (!file_.is_open()) {
        cerr << "cannot open " << f_name << endl;
        exit(1);
      } else {
        cerr << "open " << f_name << endl;
      }
    }
    void close(void) {file_.close();}
    bool is_open() {return file_.is_open();}

    friend ifstreamExt& operator >> (ifstreamExt & is, string &str) {
      is.file_ >> str;
      return is;
    }
    static void set_directory(string d) {
      _dir_ = d;
    }
  private:
    std::ifstream file_;
    static string _dir_;

};
```

Comment: Use `std::filesystem::path m_dir;` and `const std::filesystem::path& filename` instead of `std::string`. Additionally, be careful starting variable names with underscores.