# Using boost in Qt is throwing error regarding signals being defined as protected

Tags: c++, qt, boost, signals

I am trying to make a protocol stack DLL using c++. My Gui part which actually uses the protocol stack is
written in Qt. But my protocol stack is written using standard c++ alone. I want to have my 
protocol stack signal the reception of data to the GUI part asynchronously. For this, I thought of 
having a signal and slot mechanism. I didn't wanted to use Qt signal and slot because, I think, it would
force me to make my protocol stack DLL a Qt DLL. So, I thought of using boost signals.
But in Qt they are #defining signals as:

```
#define signals protected
```

This replaces all the boost signals to protected and my program throws a lot of error.
Is there a way to avoid this #defining in Boost libraries alone?
I don't want it to be stopped in Qt Libraries.

Comment: This can happen only when your project references QtCore. Is your protocol stack DLL project including QT stuff? Get rid of them to get going.

Comment: maybe this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360160/mixing-qt-and-boost) may be helpful

Comment: @Arun Protocol Stack is not using Qt stuff. But my Gui part uses it. And in order to connect Gui with protocol layer I need to have Boost in both of them. This creates the issue in Gui part. But now it got solved. I just had to use the Boost::signals2 instead of Boost::signals.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ["CONFIG      += no_keywords # so Qt won't #define any non-all-caps `keywords'"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/signals/s04.html)

Alternatively you could undefine a symbol like this:

```
    #undef signals
```

And add your own

```
    #define SIGNALS protected
```

if you want. Change protected to public though if and when you migrate to Qt 5.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But this would disable the #define in all the Qt stuff, won't it? What if Qt is internally using the name 'signals' instead of 'protected'. Wouldn't it cause some error later. I was able to use Boost::signals2 instead. Thanks again. for the Config details and pointing out the undef directive.